# Undefined offset: 0 (View: /home/me/www/me/resources/views/contact.blade.php) laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

hello i have this error : Undefined offset: 0 (View: /home/me/www/me/resources/views/contact.blade.php) i was try to create crud in admin panel for contact page. when i try to go in for edit this page, i have this error

contact.blade.php

```
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: abhi
 * Date: 10/20/2020
 * Time: 5:54 PM
 */?>


@extends('layouts.app')

<style>
    body {
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }

    .sidenav {
        height: 100%;
        width: 160px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #111;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
        padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
    }

    .sidenav a:hover {
        color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .main {
        margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
        font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
        padding: 0px 10px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
        .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
        .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }
</style>

@section('content')
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


    {{--<div class="sidenav">--}}
        {{--<a href="/post">Post</a>--}}
        {{--<a href="/category">Categories</a>--}}
        {{--<a href="/footer">Footer</a>--}}
        {{--<a href="/society">Society</a>--}}
    {{--</div>--}}



    <section style="padding-top:60px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Update Contact Details...
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            @if(Session::has('status'))
                                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                    {{Session::get('status')}}
                                </div>
                            @endif
                            <form id="insert" method="POST" action="{{url('updatecontact')}}"
                                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="h1">Address</label>
                                    <input type="text" value="{{$data[0]->address}}" name="address" class="form-control"/>

                                    <label for="h2">Contact(1)</label>
                                    <input type="tel" value="{{$data[0]->contact1}}" name="contact1" class="form-control"/>

                                    <label for="h2">Contact(2)</label>
                                    <input type="tel" value="{{$data[0]->contact2}}" name="contact2" class="form-control"/>

                                    <label for="h2">Fax</label>
                                    <input type="tel" value="{{$data[0]->fax}}" name="fax" class="form-control"/>

                                    <label for="h2">E-mail</label>
                                    <input type="email" value="{{$data[0]->email}}" name="email" class="form-control"/>

                                    <br>
                                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$data[0]->id}}" name="rowid">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Details</button>

                            </form>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        function previewFile1(input) {
            var file1 = $(input).get(0).files[0];
            if (file1) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                    $('#previewImg1').attr("src", reader.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file1);
            }
        }

    </script>

@endsection
```

I dont know where is the error i was checke all {{}} and i dont think it's here... someone have idea?

Comment: `$data` does not have a `0` index. `{{$data}}` to see what it contains

Comment: use {{ dd($data) }} in your blade to see what data it contains, if it is empty the problem lies in your controller method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel v5.6 error showing this "Undefined offset: 0 (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolmanagement\resources\views\displaycombinedata.blade.php)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612342/laravel-v5-6-error-showing-this-undefined-offset-0-view-c-xampp-htdocs-scho)

Answer (score -1):

Put an @ before your $data variable. like this :

```
{{@$data->address}}
```

PS : I dont know why anybody should vote me down. But for god sake , just before voting try it for one time! I know what Undefined offset means and my proposing method is some sort of problem solving in blade level.